# How to check if a channel has any messages? Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So what I want to achieve right now is, to find and write a code so whenever I purge the channel, it will first check if it has any messages in it. If it does not then it will send an error. The only problem is that I do not know if it's possible for the client to first check if there are any messages on it. If anyone has any ideas or examples, I would be really happy to know!

**Answer is this:**

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def clear(self, ctx, *, limit=100):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        channel = ctx.channel
        messages = await channel.history(limit=123).flatten()
        if not messages:
            await ctx.channel.send("I am really sorry but I can not purge an empty channel!")
            return
        else:
            try:
                await channel.purge(limit = limit)
                return
            except discord.Forbidden:
                return await ctx.channel.send('I do not have perms')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `messages = await channel.history(limit=123).flatten()` to get a list containing channel's messages. Limit is used to specify a maximum number of messages to read back.

You can check if that list is empty or not to check if there are messages in a channel.

API Reference: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=history#discord.TextChannel.history

Comment: So I'll basically add that and then try, `if not messages:`?

Comment: Sure. I haven't tried it myself, but I think that would work.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't seem to be working still... It continues purging without sending the error message. I'll edit my answer so you can see the code.

Comment: That's it. Everything else works fine except the first lines about the no messages error

Comment: Print messages see what it returns. I'd expect it's got your !clear command cause it's not deleting the message to clear the channel before checking for additional messages

Comment: Well I did it and the results are these `0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 8` (I edited the answer so you can find where I put the prints) . The channel was 100% empty. So I guess when I type the command it checks my cmd message too... Is there any way to buypass that or something?

Comment: You misunderstood what I meant. I meant type `print(messages)` to see what the array contained.

Comment: Oh my bad! I did it and I got this `[<Message id=810891723009163334 channel=<TextChannel id=783049127008272459 name='off-topic' position=5 nsfw=False news=False category_id=783049127008272456> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<User id=434843854030635009 name='xXSkillexZ' discriminator='1810' bot=False> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228750/discussion-between-kelo-and-xxskillexz).